# Unable to by pass the keycloak login page programmatically using springboot

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I'm unable to avoid keycloak login page/ Unable to authenticate Keycloak programmatically

I have tried getting the access token and refresh token and then passing the access token to get the master details as below, but unable to by pass the keycloak login page/

Springboot code

```
@GetMapping("/authenticatekeyclok")
 public HttpEntity keyclock() 
{
    String res=""; HttpEntity<String> response=null;
    System.out.println("enter into keycloak====");
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
    String url = "http://10.209.22.23:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token";
    String dataJSON = "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&client_id=security-admin-console&client_secret=135c0e89-c5f5-4499-a64e-c5219f59f31d";
    HttpEntity formEntity = new HttpEntity<>(dataJSON, headers);
    System.out.println("print headers===="+formEntity.getBody());
    //Trying to get tokens
    response = restTemplate.exchange("http://10.209.22.23:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token", HttpMethod.POST, formEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println("response generated============= ");
    System.out.println("O/P : for first api"+response.getBody());
    StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(response.getBody(),",");
    StringTokenizer st1;
    String s="";
    String refreshtoken=null;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        s=st.nextToken();
        if(s.contains("refresh_token")) {
            st1=new StringTokenizer(s,":");
            while(st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                refreshtoken=st1.nextToken();
                refreshtoken= refreshtoken.substring(1,refreshtoken.length()-1);
                System.out.println(refreshtoken);
            }
        } 
    }

    dataJSON = "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=security-admin-console&client_secret=135c0e89-c5f5-4499-a64e-c5219f59f31d&redirect_uri=http://10.209.22.23:5555/auth/admin/master/console/#/realms/master&refresh_token="+refreshtoken;
    HttpEntity entity1 = new HttpEntity<>(dataJSON, headers);
    response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity1, String.class);
    System.out.println("O/P for 2nd ====================== : "+response.getBody());
    st= new StringTokenizer(response.getBody(),",");
    s="";
    String accesstoken=null;
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        s=st.nextToken();
        if(s.contains("access_token")) {
            st1=new StringTokenizer(s,":");
                  while(st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                      accesstoken=st1.nextToken();
                      accesstoken= accesstoken.substring(1,accesstoken.length()-1);
                      System.out.println(accesstoken);
                  }
        } 
    }
    dataJSON=""; //ResponseEntity<String> respo = null;
    HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();
    headers1.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers1.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+accesstoken);
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers1);
    //Pass the access token and trying to go to admin console of keycloak
    response = restTemplate.exchange("http://10.209.22.23:8080/auth/admin/master/console", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    System.out.println("O/P for third======================: "+response.getBody());
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting `backchannel` requests. This is surely achievable without any visibility at browser or front-end.

You will find [sample code](https://github.com/git-adarsh/config-idp-keycloak/blob/master/java/com/auth/ms/services/DefaultOpenIDServices.java) helpful.